# Open certain number of files java

Tags: java

I want to open X number of file(s) when a user prompts for a file. If the user decides to open file1, only file1 will display. If file3 is prompt, then file1 to file3 will display and etc. How can I go about doing this?

```
System.out.print("Pick a file to open:");
String promptFile = keyboard.nextLine();
Scanner fileNumber = new Scanner(new File(promptFile ));
```

Comment: Have you named the files in the same fashion?

Comment: @zulkarnain Yes, just different numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can store your filenames in a string array:

```
String [] filenames = {"file1", "file2", "file3"} //etc
```

Then you just need to run a loop with a loop variable ranging from 1 to `promptFile`, then inside the loop you have to go thru each member of `filenames` and open it for display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple program to do your requirement

```
    String dir = ".";
    File directory = new File(dir);
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    int count = 0;
    for (File f : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile())
            map.put(count++, f.getName());
    }
    System.out.println("Index -> Files");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
    }
    System.out.print("Enter index to open file ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fileIndex = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
    String fileName = map.get(fileIndex);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String str = null;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    br.close();
```

You can add a loop to get input from user and display some other file in the directory, add conditions to avoid `Exception`s